# Dropping extra column in Tab delim file

Tags: r

I tried to merge different tab delim files into single file using the following R command.

If you observe, I even save the file using write.table command. Now i need to read the same files for further analysis. The biggest problem I am facing is that there is an extra column without any column name created automatically.[image: Screen shot of delim file opened in excel with Extra column(Red)] If you observe that there is a column (Red colour) created automatically when I use the write.table function.
I want to get rid of that column as it hampers all further calculations.[image: My actual output like how I need it to be saved]

```
combine=function(file) { 
split_list <- unlist(strsplit(file,split=","))
setwd("D:/combine")
dataset <- do.call("cbind",lapply(split_list,FUN=function(files) { read.table(files,header=TRUE, sep="\t") } ) )
names(dataset)[1]=paste("Probe_ID")
drop=c("ProbeID")
dataset=dataset[,!(names(dataset)%in%drop)]
dataset$X=NULL
write.table(dataset,file="D:/output/illumina.txt",sep="\t",col.names=NA)
return ("illumina.txt") 
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the argument `row.names=FALSE` in `write.table`.

Comment: James.if you observe the names of my column you will find the "X"is appended to array_name(ie.X448...).I dont know how to get rid this because that is not the part of array name..any help :-)

Comment: It's probably because you set `col.names=NA`. Try leaving that out, or using `col.names=TRUE`.

Comment: I did both but it is not helping..X is still added  to arrayname

Comment: Does `dataset` have column names?

Comment: Try `read.table(...,check.names = FALSE)`. I believe this happens because R nominally does not allow column/variable names to begin with a numeric character.

Comment: @james yes my dataset has column names an it starts with numerals like 4321567678_A_,4321567678_B_...

Answer (score 2):

As `@James` says -- or use `row.names=1` in `read.table()` to indicate that the first column designates the row identifiers of the table when reading the table back into `R`.